# Installing phpstorm / webstorm as Application

Tags: applications, software-installation

Is it possible somehow to install `phpstorm` and `webstorm` and having them in the application list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1:**
Go to https://www.jetbrains.com/

**Step 2:**
Download the tar.gz of the IDE you want. For eg. PhpStorm

**Step 3:**
Extract the PhpStorm.tar.gz file to your preferred location. You can use the right-click option or from the command line use: `$ tar -zxvf PhpStorm.tar.gz`

**Step 4:**
Now go to `<folder location>/PhpStorm/bin` and run the `phpstorm.sh` file. This will create an icon in the Application list as well as run the program.

Later on, when you want to start the application you can do so from the application list

Answer (score 5):

**Note: - Please note that PhpStorm and WebStorm are not FREE, so this is a 30-day trial, if you don't have activation key.**

System requirements for both [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/#section=linux-version) and [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download/#section=linux-version):

- 1 GB RAM minimum, 2 GB RAM recommended
- Oracle JRE 1.6+ or OpenJDK 1.7+
- 1024x768 minimum screen resolution
- GNOME or KDE desktop (works in elementary also)

Install dependencies:

From [official site](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/system-requirements-and-installation.html#d213132e221):

> Oracle (Sun) JDK 1.6+ or OpenJDK 1.7 or higher (OpenJDK 1.8 is recommended). Using OpenJDK is not recommended because this may result in visual and performance problems. You can use OpenJDK on your own risk if Oracle JDK causes more severe issues in your system.
>   Installation instructions:

Open terminal and run the folowing commands to install java (If you don't have):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

To install Phpstorm:

- Download [PhpStorm-10.0.3.tar.gz](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/download-thanks.html?platform=linux)
- Unpack the PhpStorm-10.0.3.tar.gz file using the following command:
  `tar xfz PhpStorm-10.0.3.tar.gz`
- Run `PhpStorm.sh` from the `bin` subdirectory

To do the above steps open terminal and run:

```
wget https://download.jetbrains.com/webide/PhpStorm-10.0.3.tar.gz
tar xvfz PhpStorm-10.0.3.tar.gz
cd PhpStorm-143.1770/bin
./phpstorm.sh
```

To Install Webstorm:

- Download [WebStorm-11.0.3.tar.gz](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download/download-thanks.html?platform=linux)
- Unpack the WebStorm-11.0.3.tar.gz file using the following command:
  `tar xfz WebStorm-11.0.3.tar.gz`
- Run WebStorm.sh from the bin subdirectory

To do the above steps open terminal and run:

```
wget https://download.jetbrains.com/webstorm/WebStorm-11.0.3.tar.gz
tar xvfz WebStorm-11.0.3.tar.gz
cd WebStorm-*/bin
./webstorm.sh
```

To create launcher icon:

While Installing phpstorm/webstorm it will ask to create Desktop Entry.

If you haven't enable the option, later you can do that from *Configuration --> Create Desktop Entry*.

Comment: It is actually `Tools -> Create Desktop Entry...`.

Answer (score 0):

1. download the web storm from https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download/#section=linux
2. after open terminal use Alt+Ctrl+t  and type `$ sudo su`  enter give your pass word get root permission.
3. enter `cd Downloads` get in to the directory.
4. enter `cd WebStorm-171.4694.29/`
5. enter `cd bin`
6. enter `sudo chmod +x webstorm.sh`
7. enter `./webstorm.sh` now the web storm run

> you can type `ls`  bet ween each `cmd` and  looking inside the list of items in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

similar script for install or update(auto) jetbrains products like phpstorm, webstorm, IntelliJ Idea and other. + dependencies + non latin hotkeys fixes
https://gist.github.com/zabidok/8418c4f679741f585ac9ce90b16fb8a5