# How to uninstall webstorm

Tags: software-installation

I installed webstorm using [directions](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3949/installing-phpstorm-webstorm-as-application) on another question.  I launched intellij and webstorm at the same time the first time I launched webstorm.  Then my machine froze.  I had to hard restart.  Now webstorm will not launch from the applications menu.  I launched `/tmp/webstorm/bin/webstorm.sh` and it re-opened webstorm.  I don't want to run a shell script to launch webstorm.

How can I uninstall webstorm?  I want to redo the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rm -rf ~/.WebStorm2017.1/` or whatever version you have intalled.  Then just re-run the installer.  Reinstalling corrected my installation failure.

Note:  Be sure to unpack the `webstorm.tar.gz` files to a permanent location (not `/tmp`) like `~/Applications`.  This way webstorm will not delete itself when you close it >.<